# Examples of Advanced Java Applications

Tags: java, java-ee-6

I'm looking for a few examples of Advanced Java Applications, Web Based and Desktop Based.

Comment: Your question is very broad. Are you looking for a type of app in particular like Forum, Server/Client Applications etc. or do you just want to see what designs and best practices some of those big applications use?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at any Atlassian product, they're pretty "advanced":

http://www.atlassian.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net/), an indie game with 1.7 million sales, is written in Java. However it is closed source so you probably can't learn much from it if that's what you want.